# Protect Branch in GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-branch

[image]

I have created a repository and have multiple branches in it. I want to restrict the developer user who has write access , from committing any code to two of our branches. Hence we made those branches as protected but still he was able to commit to those branches.

In the settings it shows Protect branch from force pushing but i wanted to protect that branch from any push so that no developer can push this to branch.
I earlier used protected branch for branch level protection but I am not seeing that option anymore now in github.

As per document it says:

> A protected branch:
>
> Can't be force pushed [i wanted to protect that branch from any push]
> Can't be deleted
> Can't have changes merged into it until required status checks pass
> Can't have changes merged into it until required reviews are approved
> Can't be edited or have files uploaded to it from the web
> Can't have changes merged into it until changes to files that have a designated code owner have been approved by that owner

Comment: After protecting it, you'll also need to enable branch restrictions: https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/

Comment: Before anyone answers, did you go through the entire [online documentation for protected branches](https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks) ?

Comment: @Rob: Branch restriction I don see that option and secondly branch restriction is for users  who can push to this branch. I want to protect from anyone. attached screnshot

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Yes very first thing I did then I posted. Thanks for highlighting it .

Comment: @Rob is right: branch restriction is what you need!

Comment: @AbhikDey On second thought; this functionality may only be available for organizational repositories

Comment: Pushing isn't the same as committing. Committing just commits to the local database, so protecting the branch against pushes just stops them being pushed up to the repo

Comment: @Rob: Yeah I have organizational repositories but as uploaded in the screenshot i have those many options and secondly in the enable branch restriction link, it says if you want some adminstrators to allow push to this branch which I don need right now. I need the branch to be protected from any push. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow: Yes thats what is not happening. After protection as per the uploaded screenshot, anyone was able to push the changes to repo

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.